# Where to store images for a website in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I am making a react E-comm site where I have 1000+ images to store..
I saw the way myntra stores their images `https://assets.myntassets.com/...`

How to store images in this way or where can I get more details about this concept?

The same concept is used by `algoexpert.io` which is a react website and their images are stored like [this](https://assets.algoexpert.io/g1ec323b14b-prod/dist/images/goLogo.png?ddcc76d9)

Comment: You can use something like Amazon AWS S3 to store the images and then point to them in your own website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Cloudinary or Imgur to upload and images through code. You can go through their Documentation. Cloudinary offer 25GB free storage in their free plan.

[Documentation Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_video_and_file_upload)